# Update JQVMap - map with new values (color change)

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, ajax, jqvmap

Hi I use JQVMap to show some values over the tooltip in a country. When the value isn't 0 the country is colored green. But I have some problems with it. To initiate the function I use the follow code. The data I get over an div. All works good. If I make an selection (with an datepicker) the data is updated in the tooltip on the map. So the right values are given to the map. But if I change to an other for example day where the value is 0 the map is still colored like there is an value over 0. So not the new -> the old map. If I make a manuell site refresh for example (with F5) it show the right map with the right values.

What can I do to get it working?

The code to initial:

```
initJQVMAP: function () {

    var showMap = function (name) {
        jQuery('.vmaps').hide();
        jQuery('#vmap_' + name).show();
    }

    var setMap = function (name) {
        var data = {
            map: 'world_en',
            backgroundColor: null,
            borderColor: '#333333',
            borderOpacity: 0.5,
            borderWidth: 1,
            color: '#c6c6c6',
            enableZoom: true,
            hoverColor: '#244671',
            hoverOpacity: null,
            values: sample_data,
            normalizeFunction: 'linear',
            scaleColors: ['#cfe9d3', '#3cc051'],
            selectedColor: '#244671',
            selectedRegion: null,
            showTooltip: true,
            onLabelShow: function (event, label, code) {

            }
        };

        data.map = name + '_en';
        var map = jQuery('#vmap_' + name);
        if (!map) {
            return;
        }
        map.width(map.parent().parent().width());
        map.show();
        map.vectorMap(data);
        map.hide();
    }

    setMap("world");
    setMap("europe");
    setMap("germany");
    showMap("world");


    jQuery('#regional_stat_world').click(function () {
        showMap("world");
    });

    jQuery('#regional_stat_usa').click(function () {
        showMap("usa");
    });

    jQuery('#regional_stat_europe').click(function () {
        showMap("europe");
    });
    jQuery('#regional_stat_russia').click(function () {
        showMap("russia");
    });
    jQuery('#regional_stat_germany').click(function () {
        showMap("germany");
    });

    $('#region_statistics_loading').hide();
    $('#region_statistics_content').show();
},
```

The code to update the values:

```
    $('#div_session_write').load('sessionstart.php?datum1=' + Date.today().add({
       days: -29
    }).toString('yyyy-MM-dd') +'&datum2=' + Date.today().toString('yyyy-MM-dd'));
    $('#geodaten').load('geodata.php');
```

I think I must redraw or reload it... but how?

Answer (score 0):

I think you shouldn't use load function. If you use ajax with async false could work fine.

```
onLabelShow: function(event, label, code) {
    myUrl="data/13historical_"+v_mapa+".php";
    $.ajax({
        url: myUrl,
        dataType: 'json',
        async: false,
        success: function(data) {
            $.each(data.votacionData.votaciones.details[0].detail, function(i) {
                if (this[0]==code) {
                    code.replace(/ /g, '_');
                    theTable='<table cellpadding=2 border=0 class="hoverTable">';
                    theTable += "<tr><td><h1 style='color: white'>"+this[1]+"</h1></td></tr>";
                    theTable += "<tr><td>Ganador</td><td>"+this[2]+"</td></tr>";
                    theTable += "<tr><td>Votos</td><td>"+this[3]+"</td></tr>";
                    theTable += "<tr><td>Segundo</td><td>"+this[8]+"</td></tr>";
                    theTable += "<tr><td>Votos</td><td>"+this[9]+"</td></tr>";
                    theTable += "</table>";
                }
            });
        }
    });
    label[0].innerHTML = v_mapa + " \n " + theTable;
}
```